# Typescript debugging with Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to bind breakpoints in my code, but I'm getting this from the visual code:

"This breakpoint was initially set in:
C:\workspace\N3urons\order-service\src\entities\Order\OrderController.ts line 595 column 1

We couldn't find a corresponding source location, but found some other files with the same name:
file:///C:/workspace/N3urons/order-service/src/entities/Order/OrderController.ts

C:/workspace/N3urons/order-service/src/entities/Order/OrderController.ts

If this is the same file, you may need to adjust your build tool to correct the paths."

I'm coding on Windows and Visual Studio doesn't find the file, but finds matching files with these slashes.
Could someone help me with this?

My launch.json looks like this:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Node: Nodemon",
      "processId": "${command:PickProcess}",
      "restart": true,
      "protocol": "inspector"
    },
    {
      "name": "Docker: Attach to Node",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "port": 9231,
      "address": "localhost",
      "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "remoteRoot": "/usr/src/service",
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "/usr/src/service/*": "${workspaceRoot}/*"
      },
      "protocol": "inspector",
      "restart": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.